# how to insert random integers to a particular column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have an existing table "public.trip_info" in PostgreSQL and I added a new column "zone" to it and now I wanted to insert random integers between 1 to 80 in the column.So I know how to generate random numbers 1 to 80 in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT floor(random() * 80 + 1)::int;
```

How to insert this to the column for all the rows.
I am new to SQL Script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
update public.trip_info
    set zone = floor(random() * 80 + 1)::int;
```

Comment: @RKR . . . The question is specifically about numbers from 1 to 80.  If you have another question, you should ask as a question and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I had written in postgres. However, idea is pretty much the same for all SQL based databases.

In order to insert a random value into a new column, you must do an UPDATE against the table.

Below is an example using MySQL:

-- Initial create & insert

```
mysql> create table t1(
    -> name varchar(20)
    -> ); 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values('blah blah blah'), ('aaa'); 
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1; 
+----------------+
| name           |
+----------------+
| blah blah blah |
| aaa            |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- alter table

```
mysql> alter table t1 add zone int not null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1; 
+----------------+------+
| name           | zone |
+----------------+------+
| blah blah blah |    0 |
| aaa            |    0 |
+----------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- update specific column

```
mysql> UPDATE t1 SET zone=floor(rand()*(80+1)) WHERE name='aaa';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1; 
+----------------+------+
| name           | zone |
+----------------+------+
| blah blah blah |    0 |
| aaa            |    6 |
+----------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- update entire table at once

```
mysql> UPDATE t1 SET zone=floor(rand()*(80+1));
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1; 
+----------------+------+
| name           | zone |
+----------------+------+
| blah blah blah |   67 |
| aaa            |   76 |
+----------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.It helped indeed.